# How is Glory awarded?

Tags: brawlhalla

I know Glory is awarded after each ranked season.  The 'Ranked' tab in Mallhalla states the following:

> You will earn Glory at the end of each ranked season based on your performance.

What I want to know is, how do I know exactly how much Glory I'm going to be awarded?  What is the amount based on?  It's in the thousands for me every time but I have no idea where the actual final numbers come from, specifically.

[image: Capture of the Ranked (Glory) Markletplace]

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few things that account for your Glory earnings.

- For every win you have in a season, you gain **20 Glory** with a **maximum of 3000**
- You also gain Glory based on your peak Elo (1v1 or 2v2, whichever is higher) at the end of each season (graph below)

[image: Graph of elo earned]

Furthermore, to gain any Elo at all, you must have to have played at least 10 games in Ranked.